# Regex match only allow specific words and disallow anything before

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have this injection VB script that I use for altering C# source code.
This is my current regex match rule I use currently to find code rows with classes in the files:

```
(public|protected|internal|private|static|abstract)\b\W+(class)\b
```

It works and detects class rows, but the problem is it detects all cases in the examples below, while only the first one should be valid.

```
public class  <-- is valid match
//this is a public class comment    <-- Should not be valid as match
"This is just a string talking about a public class"    <-- Should not be valid match
```

To me, what is missing is to have this match rule work is, only allow what is matched by allowed words, and make any other extra a non valid match. Well, a blank space should be the only type that should be allowed.

How to update the current regex to only match the first line of the three examples I just gave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `^\s*` to indicate it has to be at the start of a line, followed by 0 or more spaces:

`^\s*(public|protected|internal|private|static|abstract)\b\W+(class)\b`

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ls6y8w/1)

Answer (score 0):

If the **{** following the class name can be used to distinguish your 3 cases, you could modify your regex this way:

```
(public|protected|internal|private|static|abstract)\b\W+(class)\b\s*[\r\n]{0,2}\s*{
```